# Did John Christopher (a.k.a. Samuel Youd) plan or think about writing sequels to Wild Jack?

Tags: john-christopher

I suspect that if I do not know the answer to this question, probably nobody here does.  However, as a longtime fan of [John Christopher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Christopher) (real name Samuel Youd), including his lesser known works, this is a question that I have wondered about since the 1980s.

Much of Christopher's best known children's fiction was written as trilogies—*The Sword of the Spirits* trilogy, the *Fireball* trilogy, and most famously *The Tripods* (later expanded with a prequel).  He wrote a fair number of standalone novels as well, many of which I also read.  However, the standalone works seemed to be quite a bit less well known than the trilogies.  It seemed like every school or public library in 1980s America had *Fireball*, *The Prince in Waiting*, and probably multiple copies of the *Tripods* books.  On the other hand, *The Lotus Caves*, *The Guardians*, and *Empty World* were relatively rarities.

Having read most of Christopher's children's book oeuvre, I was puzzled by the fact that one of his books, *[Wild Jack](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1196884.Wild_Jack)* (1974), really seemed to me as if it should have been the beginning of a series.  As Goodreads puts it:

> In twenty-third-century England, young Clive Anderson is imprisoned in an attempt to mold him into a docile member of society but escapes to the Outlands where he is befriended by Wild Jack's outlaw band.

*Wild Jack* was not the first time the author had looked at conflict between a ruling aristocracy and the lower classes in a dangerously stratified society; that was also the topic of [The Guardians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guardians_(novel)) (1970).  However, the later *Wild Jack* has a very open ending, where Clive goes back to live with the outlaws, with the implication that he wants to fight against the oppressive hierarchical system.

So I am wondering whether Youd ever indicated that he thought of *Wild Jack* as the potential beginning of a longer series of books.  Or was the open ending never intended to get any kind of resolution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a publication called *Something About the Author*, one edition  (volume 6, pages 297–312, published 1988) of which quoted Sam Youd/John Christopher himself [as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONSn1.jpg):

> *Wild Jack* is different again. It was planned as the first part of a
>   trilogy, and in fact I completed a second book. This was shown to my
>   English publisher, and when she disliked it I withdrew it from offer.
>   This is not the only time I've withdrawn a book on the basis of a
>   single rejection, but it's always hard: one has lived with the story
>   and the characters for months, and it isn't easy to accept that the
>   struggle has been in vain.
>
> In this case, though, I was able to analyse what I felt had gone
>   wrong. *In the Beginning* was a piece of allegorical fiction, and the
>   two main characters represented types - humours - rather than
>   individuals. It could be transformed into the longer *Dom and Va* without
>   much difficulty. But in *Wild Jack* characterization was more
>   important, and the relatively basic English in which it was originally
>   written did not provide enough linguistic subtlety for anything beyond stock characters. While I could manage to struggle through the
>   adaptation of the original book, the sequel cruelly showed up a fundamental inadequacy.

Comment: That was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!